# Flutter 2.0 - New buttons style

Tags: flutter

I updated a project to new version of Flutter, some of properties is changed.

For example

```
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
       primary: Colors.blue[700],
       highlightColor: Colors.black)
```

Return that *highlightColor* parameter doesn´t exist.

In other case

```
 style: TextButton.styleFrom(                 
     splashColor: Colors.white24,
     backgroundColor: Colors.black),
```

Return *splashColor* parameter doesn´t exist.

So, how can i set *highlightColor* and *splashColor* in new version of Flutter (2.0.3)?

Answer (score 1):

For Splash affect You can use ButtonStyle :

```
 ButtonStyle(
       overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.red),
    ),
```

---

overlayColor → MaterialStateProperty<Color?>?
The highlight color that's typically used to indicate that the button is focused, hovered, or pressed.
final